# beamer struggling with subfig   (subfig doesn't work!)

Tags: beamer, floats

I want to put multiple figures in one frame.
I am trying different combinations but neither works.
I used `subfigure` (worked) but I didn't manage to put in a proper way the figures.

As I read, it's better to use `subfig` (and also it's easier for me), but it seems `subfig` always throw a lot of errors (and it opens the `subfig.sty` file).

```
\documentclass[10pt,blue]{beamer}

 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
 \setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{url}


 %\usepackage{caption}%,subcaption}



 \usepackage{ graphicx, amsmath, amssymb, lettrine}


\newcommand{\EN}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\EN{title}}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{cad-}\label{lab1}}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{grid}\label{lab2}}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{grid}\label{lab3}}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{grid}\label{lab4}}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{grid}\label{lab5}}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{grid}\label{lab6}}

%\caption{\EN{text} \protect\subref{lab1} \EN{some text} 
%  \protect\subref{lab2} \EN{ text}}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---------------UPDATE----------------------------------

Even with that setup doesn't work.. It seems `subfig` doesn't work. It opens the `subfig.sty` file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}


\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

---------------UPDATE 2---------------------------------------

Beginning of `log` file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=xelatex 2012.7.6)  9 SEP 2012 17:49
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**forstack.tex
(./forstack.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, ibycus, monogreek, greek, ancientgreek, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 91.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen102
\Gin@req@width=\dimen103
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamer.cls
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasercs.sty
Package: beamerbasercs 2007/01/28 (rcs-revision 1.4)
)
Document Class: beamer 2007/03/11 cvs version 3.07 A class for typesetting pres
entations (rcs-revision 1.70)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/beamerbasemodes.sty
```

The first errors:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \ext@figure 
l.298 ...ined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}}{}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.298 ...ined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}}{}

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Extra \endcsname.
\@ifundefined ...dafter \ifx \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  \relax \expandafter \@firs...
l.298 ...ined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}}{}

I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \ext@figure 
l.298 ...ined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}}{}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\newcounter ...ifdefinable \csname c@#1\endcsname 
                                                  {\@definecounter {#1}}\@if...
l.298 ...ined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}}{}

I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
```

Comment: The error you get should be self-explaining: you're loading `subcaption` along `subfig`. Load only one of them.

Comment: @egreg :No, it still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, but "doesn't work" means nothing. What's not working?

Comment: @egreg:As i said,it show a lot of errors (138) and it opens the subfig.sty file to this point "\@ifundefined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}}{}".

Comment: You are loading lots of packages and any of them can cause problems. So this is not a MWE because you can take out packages one by one and see if the output has changed such that we don't have to guess your remaining document. Nevertheless, try with `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`. Also are you using XeLaTeX?

Comment: @George Like the other time, this code (after removing `subcaption`) doesn't produce *any* error on my machine.

Comment: @percusse :i updated and still problem.Yes i use xelatex..

Comment: xelatex doesn't play well with beamer. I'm not saying there's a specific problem, but definitely cause for concern. If you believe that subfig is the issue, then remove all the font spec related commands, and compile with pdflatex and see if you get the same errors

Comment: @Suresh:I cannot compile with pdflatex (i don't know why,it doesn't work).If i remove "fontspec" it gives a lot of errors (i think because i use polyglossia).

Comment: Right. remove that as well. the goal is just to get an MWE

Comment: @Suresh:I updated,it doesn't work either..

Comment: @George I've compiled the last example with XeLaTeX under TeX Live 2010, 2011 and 2012 with no error whatsoever. Of course `inputenc` shouldn't be used with XeLaTeX, but in this case it can't do any harm, because only ASCII characters are found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following, modified form of your MWE (i) doesn't throw any errors and (ii) manages to place all six "figures" side-by-side. Because I don't have access to the files `cad-[.pdf]` and `grid[.pdf]`, note that I had to load the `graphicx` package with the `demo` option set (which will just create a black blob in lieu of loading an actual graphics file).

Furthermore, since I have no idea what the natural scale of your graphics files may be, I've replaced all `[scale=0.55]` instructions with `[width=1.4cm]` instructions. I've also inserted various `\hspace{1mm}` instructions to create some separation between the subfloats.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove this in final version
\documentclass[10pt,blue]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{url}

%\usepackage{caption}%,subcaption}

\usepackage{ amsmath, amssymb, lettrine} % don't load graphicx package again -- beamer already does that

\newcommand{\EN}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\EN{title}}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=1.4cm]{cad-}\label{lab1}}
\hspace{1mm}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=1.4cm]{grid}\label{lab2}}
\hspace{1mm}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=1.4cm]{grid}\label{lab3}}
\hspace{1mm}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=1.4cm]{grid}\label{lab4}}
\hspace{1mm}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=1.4cm]{grid}\label{lab5}}
\hspace{1mm}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=1.4cm]{grid}\label{lab6}}

%\caption{\EN{text} \protect\subref{lab1} \EN{some text} 
%  \protect\subref{lab2} \EN{ text}}

\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: :First of all thanks for your help.Unfortunately this also doesn't work.I receive a lot of errors.First,it opens the subfig.sty file in line " \@ifundefined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}}{}".

Comment: :And some of the errors are: "Missing \endcsname inserted.....ined{c@subfigure}{\newsubfloat{figure}{} ",   " Use of \the doesn't match its definition." ,       "Unknwon option `caption=false'for package subfig "    ,  "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \RequireXeTex "   , " Missing number,treated as zero \RequireXeTex"

Comment: @George - please indicate which TeX distribution you use. (I use MacTeX 2012 with all updates applied, and I get no error messages at all.) You are running XeLaTeX, right?

Comment: :yes, i run xelatex ,  i use versions latex-beamer-3.20 and texlive-latex-2012 , texlive-latex-recommended (2009-7) ,texlive-latex-extra (2009-7)

Comment: I think you have some problems with your `tex` installation. Make sure that only TeXLive 2012 and the actual `beamer` is used.

Comment: @George: You may have TeXLive2009 lurking around somewhere, interfering with TeXLive2012. Which operating system do you run?

Comment: @Mico:Sorry i have texlive-2009 .All the packages are 2009.I use Linux . (the 2012 was from my other distribution where i have other problems there..).

Comment: @Mico:Ok, the problem solved!Must install all the 2012 packages!Thanks!