# center the listings title above the code

Tags: listings

I can't manage to center the title  "Listing:1" over the listing.

```
\documentclass[8pt,blue]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{float} % for images
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,163,82}
\definecolor{structure}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
  tabsize=4,
  rulecolor=,
  language=c++,
      basicstyle=\scriptsize,
      upquote=true,
      aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
      columns=flexible,
      showstringspaces=false,
      extendedchars=true,
      breaklines=true,
      numbers=none,
      prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
      %frame=false,
      showtabs=false,
      showspaces=false,
      showstringspaces=false,
      identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
      keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
      commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
      stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},    
}

\newcommand{\EN}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{intro}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}


\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption= code 1]
int main(void) {
    printf("Left\n");
    return 0;
}

\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption= code 2]
int main(void) {
    printf("Right\n");
    return 0;

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I receive:

[image]

I want the title to be centered above the code.

Comment: Actually, it *is* centred. You just want it to be above the listing so that it looks like it's centred.

Comment: @Werner Or maybe he wants to center the listing inside the minipage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a rather small default font size (`8pt`), maximize the width of the minipages (`0.5\textwidth`), and have fairly short line lengths for the code snippets inside the listings. These factors, combined, give the impression that the captions aren't centered when they are, in fact, perfectly centered over the respective minipages -- as @Werner has already pointed out in a comment.

The easiest fix would be to use a somewhat narrower width of, say, `0.3\textwidth` for the two minipage environments. If you can make do with the normal default font size, instead of `8pt`, you should probably select something like `0.35\textwidth` for the widths of the two environments in order to avoid creating some unnecessary line breaks.

**Addendum**: Without the `8pt` document class option and setting the widths of the minipages to `0.35\textwidth`, and (for good measure) commenting out all package-loading code that's not needed for the example at hand, the following look results:

[image]

Hopefully, this is closer to what you're trying to achieve.

```
\documentclass[blue]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{greek}
%\setotherlanguage{english}

%\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{float} % for images
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{listings} 
%\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,163,82}
\definecolor{structure}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{1,1,1}

\lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
  tabsize=4,
  rulecolor=,
  language=c++,
      basicstyle=\scriptsize,
      upquote=true,
      aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
      columns=flexible,
      showstringspaces=false,
      extendedchars=true,
      breaklines=true,
      numbers=none,
      prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]
         {\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
      %frame=false,
      showtabs=false,
      showspaces=false,
      showstringspaces=false,
      identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
      keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
      commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.133,0.545,0.133},
      stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},    
}

%\newcommand{\EN}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}
\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{intro}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption= code 1]
int main(void) {
    printf("Left\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption= code 2]
int main(void) {
    printf("Right\n");
    return 0;

}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: :Hello , this didn't fix at all the problem. (i already tried changing the 0.5\textwidth ,but nothing works.I changed now and the font size but still the same)

Comment: @George -- There's a separate issue with your MWE: you shouldn't be using the `subfigure` and `subcaption` packages simultaneously. (The MWE won't compile under XeLaTeX if both packages are loaded, at least not under MacTeX2012, which is what I'm running.) Have you tried dropping, say, the `subcaption` package?

Comment: :I  tested it now,but still the same..

Comment: @George: I've posted an image file and the associated code to illustrate the changes that result from implementing my suggestions. It's difficult for me to understand that it's "still the same" (as what you posted initially).

Comment: @ Mico:It seems the removal of 8pt from \documentclass[blue]{beamer}  ,does the job.But , then the entire document goes messed up..

Comment: @George: If your `beamer` presentation truly requires the `8pt` option in order for material to fit on a page, you may be trying to pack way too much material on a page. Unless the screen you're going to be projecting the material on is truly humongous, use of the `8pt` font size option is going to force many people in the audience to squint so that they can make out what's being shown. You may want to seriously consider simplifying your entire presentation. The main mantra when preparing a presentation should always be *Less is More*: Less material on any given page, and fewer pages overall!

Comment: :Ok,thank you.Just the 8pt seems also "big" and the problem is with figures that i have and they mess up.Anyway..Maybe you can help me with this?http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70568/beamer-struggling-with-subfig(upvoted for all your trouble)

Comment: @George: I can't tell what the natural scale of the `cad-` and `grid` image files may be. Instead of setting the option `[scale=0.55]`, you may want to try setting an option such as `[width=0.25\textwidth]`.

Comment: @ Mico:The problem is that subfig package doesn't work.(i will update because its in the comments))